# Conversion of Maxwell's Equations to Ohm's Law

Tags: capacitance, maxwell-equations

I am working on electric currents in Comsol and have the following set of simplified equations:
$$ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{J} = Q_{j,v} \\ \mathbf{E} = -\nabla V \\ \mathbf{J} = \sigma \mathbf{E} + \frac{\partial \mathbf{D}}{\partial t} + \mathbf{J}_e = \sigma \mathbf{E}$$

I understand that the divergence of the current density is the charge per unit volume (divergence of a flux continuity equation)
I know $V=ED$ and this is expressed as the gradient shown for 3D integration. But the last equation relates the current density to the electric field, partial of the displacement field and the external current. We know that the displacement field is defined as:
$$\mathbf{D} = \varepsilon_0 \mathbf{E} + \mathbf{P}$$

I see the permittivity and polarization which I typically associate with capacitance. Is this term to do with capacitive coupling? Specifically when taking the partial derivative of the displacement field we will get the curl of a magnetic field and the partial of the polarization. Is just the partial of the polarization wrt time due to capacitive coupling? I thought capacitive coupling was dependent on both the amplitude of the voltage and the frequency?

Comment: Your last equation seems wrong, $\sigma \mathbf E$ is on both sides of the equation. Second, what are $\mathbf J, \mathbf J_e$? Also you have to decide what kind of medium you are describing. For dielectric, total real electric current is $\mathbf j = \frac{\partial \mathbf P}{\partial t}$ and for the simplest model of linear optically nonactive dielectric, we have $\mathbf P(t) = \epsilon_0 \int_0^\infty \chi(\tau)\mathbf E(t-\tau)d\tau$. For conductor it is better to forget about/ignore $\mathbf P$ and work directly with $\mathbf j(t) = \int_0^\infty \sigma(\tau) \mathbf E(t-\tau)d\tau$.

Comment: @JánLalinský yes i simplified the last equation by cutting out the $$ \frac{\partial P}{\partial t} $$ and the external current. The external current (Je) is an option in comsol regarding an external current source. Regardless we know J=Jf+Jb. Jb is the $$ \frac{\partial P}{\partial t} $$ term thus i assume it is also the term involved in capacitive coupling

Comment: Coupling of what with what? I don't see what you mean.

Comment: In a transformer, real current is mostly in winding, and some in the core, because the core is made of ferromagnetic plates that are conductive (the plates suppress eddy currents but not completely). I don't see why you jump from this to displacement current $\frac{\partial D}{\partial t}$. That is a completely different thing and can often be ignored (certainly in AC transformer).